# $\int_{G/H} \alpha \quad $

Tags: integration, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $H$ be Lie subgroup of $G$. Let $\alpha$ be a differential form on $G/H$. Is there exists  a way to express the integral $$\int_{G/H} \alpha \quad $$
using integral over $G$ and  integral over $H$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by function of an integral?

Comment: I meant express $\int_{G/H} \alpha$ using $\int_G$ and $\int_H$. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: What could be suitable forms to integrate over $G$ and $H$ resp. since we only have a $1$-form $\alpha$ on $G/H$?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question!

Comment: Could you please elaborate further why do we have only a 1-form on $G/H$ ?

Comment: Missread. I didn't mean to write "$1$-form" but "form $\alpha$ on $G/H$". For instance one could try and lift $\alpha$ to $G$ using the pullback with the canonical projection $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H$. The pulled-back form $\pi^*\alpha$ is in some suitable sense 'constant' along the preimages $\pi^{-1}(p)$, $p\in G/H$. This is similar to lifting $f(x):=x$ to $(\pi^*f)(x,y)=f(x)=x$, where $\pi(x,y)=x$.

Comment: @dennis_s, if I understand correctly your comment, $\int_{G/H}\alpha = \int_G \pi^*(\alpha)$ since $\pi^*(\alpha)$ is constant along the fibers $\pi^{-1}(p)$ ?

Comment: Be aware that $\int_{G/H} \alpha \neq \int_G \pi^*\alpha$ in general. Back to functions $f$ on an interval $[0,1]$ lifted to a rectangle $[0,1]\times[a,b]$ we have that $\int_{[0,1]}f\ dx$ = $\int_{[0,1]\times[a,b]}(\pi^*f)\ dxdy \cdot (b-a)^{-1}$.

Comment: I think that the key point is to use the existence of the haar measure on compact Lie groups. I will read more about that subject and come back here when I finish. Thank you much @dennis_s for your helpful comments.